# Check if a view belongs to a linearlayout or not

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-view

I need a little help.
How I can check is a view belongs to a linearlayout or not?

I have an ImageButton and i need a condition that verify if belongs to a linearlayout or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [findViewById](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById%28int%29) method on the LinearLayout. From the JavaDoc "Look for a child view with the given id. If this view has the given id, return this view."

```
LinearLayout layoutWithButton = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_with_button);
ImageButton buttonInLayout = (ImageButton)layoutWithButton.findViewById(R.id.button_in_layout);

if (buttonInLayout != null) {
  // Found
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Haven't tried this, but it should work.
Assuming that your ImageButton is always a direct child of your LinearLayout.

```
View parent = (View)mContent.getParent();
if (parent instanceof LinearLayout) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Hi sblom and frank. Thanks for your reply. My brain crash. XDXD. I post my solutin. Thanks for your help

Comment: Your solution tells you if you are in a specific ViewGroup. This solution tells you if you are in any LinearLayout (which was the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Try searching the UI tree via the getParent() method

Comment: Hi comodoro. Thanks for your reply. It's simple, but I'm tired and my brain crash XDXD. LinearLayout contentLayoutAddressPostal = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.se_contentAdressPostal); ImageButton imbtRemoveAddress2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.sfsp2_ivHide); if(imbtRemoveAddress2.getParent()==contentLayoutAddressPostal){
       imbtRemoveAddress2.performClick();

Answer (score 0):

The solution.....

```
      LinearLayout contentLayoutAddressPostal = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.se_contentAdressPostal);

     ImageButton imbtRemoveAddress2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.sfsp2_ivHide);

       if(imbtRemoveAddress2.getParent()==contentLayoutAddressPostal){
          imbtRemoveAddress2.performClick();
                                    ............................
```